# Unable to show geometry in virtual layer qgis

Tags: qgis, postgresql, virtual-layer

I'm trying to create a virtual layer starting from a municipality layer and from a  table of attributes, both stored in a Postgresql DB.

So I've done a join like:

```
*SELECT munic, country_of_origin, SUM (presence), munic.NOME
FROM ps JOIN munic ON munic.pro_com = ps.pro_com
WHERE country_of_origin = 'Germany'
GROUP BY munic.NOME
ORDER BY munic.NOME DESC*
```

I've set the geometry fields in the mask, I see the join in the attribute table, but I can't see the map

Any ideas?

Comment: `"even if i've set the geometry fields in the mask"` ... what do u mean ?

Comment: Do you need to add a geometry field to your selection? In a quick test, doing `"SELECT ID from foo"` fails, but `"SELECT ID,ID.geometry from foo"` works for me. (`"SELECT * from foo"` also works)

Comment: It's not enough to list the geometry column -- if a GROUP BY is present, you need to use an aggregation function on the geometry (or to restructure so that the geometry is outside the aggregation).