# Preserving geometry of Union output with Virtual Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, union, virtual-layer

There is a polygon layer *'Union23'* that was created with the "Union" tool.

[image: Polygon_Layer]

Layer's attribute table includes the following values.

[image: AT_values]

My effort is simply to aggregate those polygons by `"FLAECHEID"` field with the sum and count of a field `"In_Value1"` via a Virtual Layer. So I am using the expression:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(In_Value1),
    COUNT(In_Value1)
FROM
    Union23
GROUP BY
    "FLAECHEID"
```

However, I am getting really weird output and I do not understand why I am losing a part of geometry on the way? Any suggestions?

[image: VL_Output]

---

**References:**

- [Select all columns except geometry using virtual layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313331/select-all-columns-except-geometry-using-virtual-layers)
- [Unable to show geometry in virtual layer qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283891/unable-to-show-geometry-in-virtual-layer-qgis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a mix of an aggregate function and a regular row, SQLite will return a random row for the not-aggregated field (see [doc, point 3](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)). To overcome this, don't use `*` but properly aggregated fields, including on the geometry

```sql
SELECT ST_UNION(geometry), SUM(In_Value1), COUNT(In_Value1)
FROM Union23
GROUP BY "FLAECHEID"
```

Comment: So to say, If I want to maintain all of my fields I will need to perform it manually instead of star-symbol `*`, am I right?

Comment: Yes. with min/max etc, unless they all have the same value and a random row is OK

Comment: You could also do a join on `Flaecheid` between the spatial layer and the newly computed stat table - that would not contain any geometry -

Comment: yeap, I think this will be the best option via `Join`. thank you

Comment: I often find that unexpected results can be traced to bad geometry, particularly with shapefiles.  Consider validating both the input and output layer's geometry with Check Geometry.  You can also Repair.  Then

Comment: @JGH, why not extending your answer ? I do not want to put a new answer ... it is meaningless

Comment: @Taras because your edit had nothing to do with the question. Saying/showing that your particular geometry fails to union perfectly is not related to the fact that you need to put an aggregate on the geometry field. Feel free to add this information as a comment or as an edit to your question (but not as en edit to the answer)

Comment: idk, it is a bit strange for me. I just wanted to show that your query works well, and give the desired output, that is all ...